# Events order not as expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have an image animation code set so it happens in certain page update events. It works as expected. As the update can fail and I don't want the animation to play forever I want that it be stopped whenever the user clicks anywhere or press a key. For the key press event it is working and is this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function RefreshImg() {
            var src = $('#ocupado').attr('src');
            $('#ocupado').attr('src', src);
        }

        function processando() {
            $processando = $('#processando');
            $processando.css('z-index', '100').fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
            var left = Math.floor(($processando.outerWidth() - 32) / 2);
            var top = Math.floor(($processando.outerHeight() - 32) / 2);
            $('#ocupado').css('left', left).css('top', top);
            setTimeout(RefreshImg, 50);
            $(document).on('keypress', (function () {
                $processando.fadeOut('fast').css('z-index', '-100');
                $(this).off('keypress');
            }));
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="processando" style="border:0;position:fixed;display:none;z-index:-100;width:100%;height:100%;background:black;top:0px;left:0px;">
    <img id="ocupado" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Ajax-loader.gif" width="32" height="32" style="position:relative;" border="0" alt="imagem de espera" />
    </div>
    <select id="mySelect"><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#mySelect').change(processando);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is when I change the code to include the click event:

```
$(document).on('keypress click', (function () {
    $processando.fadeOut('fast').css('z-index', '-100');
    $(this).off('keypress click');
}));
```

Now the animation starts and stops as soon as the user changes the select option. It is as if the click event happens **after** the change event. How to make the animation to stop only at first click after the select change?

Comment: Couple of comments: 1. Change `$('body')` to `$(document)` 2. use function reference inside `setTimeout` like `setTimeout(RefreshImg, 50);`

Comment: @Vega Done here and in real code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the jQuery blur() function can do what you want. See the updated code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/j8fJZ/1/

As you can see, you can also trigger the blur on keydown.

Comment: I do understand. I added the keydown event because you mentioned you wanted it to work whenever the user clicks anywhere or press a key. And yes that lines is optional. the Blur function works because it fires whenever the user "focus" any other DOM element. Please take a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html